# How to set checked property of CheckBoxList items in aspx markup?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, checkboxlist

I have a CheckBoxList in my page, with the DataTextField and DataValueField attributes set, is there an attribute that I can use to specify a property that indicates if it should be checked?

I'm hoping to just set the datasource, and not have to have any code behind to set the checked property.  Possible?

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible because the control uses the same binding as other controls such as ListBox, DropDownList, RadioButtonList, etc.

As per MSDN:

> To set multiple selections in a list
>   control programmatically loop through
>   the control's Items collection and set
>   the Selected property of every
>   individual item.

You could implement the OnDataBinding of the CheckListBox and then do a lookup for each item that gets bound but it would probably just be easier to do it all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

lock at this example:

```
string[] strUserRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser("Ali");
foreach (var item in Roles.GetAllRoles())
{
         chkRoleList.Items.Add(new ListItem()
         {
             Text = item,
             Value = item,
             Selected = strUserRoles.Contains(item)
         });
}
```

Note: when you bind CheckListBox, you must set Both of Text and Value of each Item.